# the style of my web dont work in the heroku enviroment

Tags: css, heroku, sass, styles, package.json

i did a simple style to my page with a navbar and some colors, and in my localhost worked fine and look like this:
[image]

but when i wanted to put it in production in heroku, the first try when i put my app in heroku the page give me an error, it tell me that it not have webpack to run the app, so i try to put it in the dependencies, but when i put something strange happend, now i can run the page but the style of the page dont load, according to the error messages for some reason in the production page the file 'index.scss' can not be found, here is the link to my [app](https://proy-web.herokuapp.com/), and you will see that the style dont load, i have search a lot, and dont get any aswer. if you see the console you will see something like this:

[image]

i am sure that the problem have to be something trivial, because in my localhost run perfectly, here i will put de package.json file and other file that i thing could be the problem:

here is the package.json without the webpack in the dependencies, the page that is in the link, have this webpack in the dependencies `"webpack": "^4.44.1"`, i am working with node 12 in my localhost:

```
{
  "name": "proy_web1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "lint": "eslint ./src index.js",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix ./src index.js",
    "build-assets": "yarn run clean-assets && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
    "clean-assets": "rm -rf build/assets",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn run build-assets && sequelize db:migrate",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "koa-webpack": "^6.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-command": "^0.5.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "koa": "^2.13.0",
    "koa-body": "^4.2.0",
    "koa-ejs": "^4.3.0",
    "koa-flash-message": "^0.1.6",
    "koa-logger": "^3.2.1",
    "koa-override-method": "^1.0.0",
    "koa-router": "^9.4.0",
    "koa-session": "^6.0.0",
    "koa-static": "^5.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
    "pg": "^8.3.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x || 12.x",
    "yarn": "^1.22.0"
  }
}
```

the file index.scss is this, only call to the file that have the style of the page nothing more:

```
@import './layout';
@import './hello';
```

here i will out another 2 file that i thing could give some hint:
the src/assets/js/index.js:

```
import './assets';
import '../styles/index.scss';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log('App is running on the browser too!');
```

here i will put what i get in the console log of heroku:

```
2021-05-11T18:47:07.144827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=proy-web.herokuapp.com request_id=544ed2f6-a3f2-48e2-b774-7de4984fc278 fwd="190.215.243.21" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1112 protocol=https

2021-05-11T18:47:07.426905+00:00 app[web.1]:   <-- GET /assets/layout.scss

2021-05-11T18:47:07.429649+00:00 app[web.1]:   --> GET /assets/layout.scss 404 3ms -

2021-05-11T18:47:07.433955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/layout.scss" host=proy-web.herokuapp.com request_id=418f0279-6cd3-467f-b240-8adb087ed74c fwd="190.215.243.21" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=151 protocol=https

2021-05-11T18:47:07.595122+00:00 app[web.1]:   <-- GET /assets/logo-ea7b6c88808990265c1df02a53f5e0a8.png

2021-05-11T18:47:07.599021+00:00 app[web.1]:   --> GET /assets/logo-ea7b6c88808990265c1df02a53f5e0a8.png 200 4ms 33.11kb

2021-05-11T18:47:07.606747+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/logo-ea7b6c88808990265c1df02a53f5e0a8.png" host=proy-web.herokuapp.com request_id=870001dc-a563-4687-a35c-f5a854ec4d81 fwd="190.215.243.21" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=34103 protocol=https

2021-05-11T18:47:07.767336+00:00 app[web.1]:   <-- GET /assets/app-c4171cfe9ddfc6d1d3b4.js

2021-05-11T18:47:07.772079+00:00 app[web.1]:   --> GET /assets/app-c4171cfe9ddfc6d1d3b4.js 200 4ms 127.89kb

2021-05-11T18:47:07.777460+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/app-c4171cfe9ddfc6d1d3b4.js" host=proy-web.herokuapp.com request_id=501765e5-3ab6-4d56-928c-6b8307681b5e fwd="190.215.243.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=131188 protocol=https

2021-05-11T18:58:03.607238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=proy-web.herokuapp.com request_id=ec101f16-4cc2-4980-a0cd-3077237ffe5a fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=136 protocol=https

2021-05-11T18:58:03.598853+00:00 app[web.1]:   <-- HEAD /

2021-05-11T18:58:03.604641+00:00 app[web.1]:   --> HEAD / 200 6ms 976b
```

and the logs in the build console is the following:

```
Enumerating objects: 10, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 14.74 KiB | 1.34 MiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.x || 12.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  ^1.22.0
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 10.x || 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.22.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.12
remote:        Resolving yarn version ^1.22.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.10)
remote:        Installed yarn 1.22.10
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:
remote:        > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_d34e8983/node_modules/ejs
remote:        > node ./postinstall.js
remote:
remote:
remote:        > core-js@3.12.1 postinstall /tmp/build_d34e8983/node_modules/core-js
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:
remote:
remote:        > core-js-pure@3.12.1 postinstall /tmp/build_d34e8983/node_modules/core-js-pure
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:
remote:
remote:        > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_d34e8983/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents
remote:        > node install.js
remote:
remote:
remote:        Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
remote:
remote:        > nodemon@2.0.7 postinstall /tmp/build_d34e8983/node_modules/nodemon
remote:        > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
remote:
remote:        Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
remote:         > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
remote:
remote:
remote:        > node-sass@4.14.1 install /tmp/build_d34e8983/node_modules/node-sass
remote:        > node scripts/install.js
remote:
remote:        Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node
remote:        Download complete
remote:        Binary saved to /tmp/build_d34e8983/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
remote:        Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.LxTGS/_cacache/node-sass/4.14.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node
remote:
remote:        > node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /tmp/build_d34e8983/node_modules/node-sass
remote:        > node scripts/build.js
remote:
remote:        Binary found at /tmp/build_d34e8983/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
remote:        Testing binary
remote:        Binary is fine
remote:        added 1729 packages in 27.859s
remote:
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:
remote:        > proy_web1@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_d34e8983
remote:        > yarn run build-assets && sequelize db:migrate
remote:
remote:        yarn run v1.22.10
remote:        $ yarn run clean-assets && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p
remote:        $ rm -rf build/assets
remote:        ⬡ webpack: Starting Build
remote:        ⬡ webpack: Build Finished
remote:
remote:        webpack v4.46.0
remote:
remote:        c4171cfe9ddfc6d1d3b4
remote:          size     name  module                                     status
remote:          40 B     3     multi ./js/index.js ./js/app.jsx           built
remote:          87 B     4     ./images/logo.png                          built
remote:          39 B     5     ./styles/index.scss                        built
remote:          178 B    10    ./js/index.js + 1 modules                  built
remote:          465 B    11    ./js/app.jsx + 1 modules                   built
remote:
remote:          size     name  asset                                      status
remote:          1.41 kB  app   app-c4171cfe9ddfc6d1d3b4.css               emitted
remote:          2.67 kB  app   app-c4171cfe9ddfc6d1d3b4.css.map           emitted
remote:          131 kB   app   app-c4171cfe9ddfc6d1d3b4.js                emitted
remote:          319 kB   app   app-c4171cfe9ddfc6d1d3b4.js.map            emitted
remote:          33.9 kB  png   logo-ea7b6c88808990265c1df02a53f5e0a8.png  emitted
remote:          293 B    json  manifest.json                              emitted
remote:
remote:          Δt 5127ms (10 modules hidden)
remote:
remote:        Done in 6.85s.
remote:
remote:        Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.22.1, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.6.2]
remote:
remote:        Loaded configuration file "src/config/database.js".
remote:        Using environment "production".
remote:        No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        removed 1035 packages and audited 694 packages in 17.813s
remote:
remote:        27 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 8 moderate severity vulnerabilities
remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 36.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v8
remote:        https://proy-web.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/proy-web.git
   9065ded..573b0d8  main -> main
```

and this is the structure of files in general, with focus in the folder assets:

[image]

i am new in this world of styles so is very posible that i didn t give all the file that you need to help me so pls, ask me for those and i will put it :D.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have load `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, and `node-sass` in the `devDependencies`. On pushing your code to Heroku, it automatically removes the `devDependencies`. On the local machine, you are using them and hence your code is working but on Heroku `devDependencies` are not going to be installed.
To solve this problem you have to move `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, and `node-sass` from the `devDependencies` to the `dependencies`.

To do so run the following command:

```
npm install sass-loader css-loader node-sass --save-prod
```

After adding these modules to dependencies push your code to the Heroku.

> You should use `Dart Sass` because the `node-sass` has been deprecated now.

Comment: i will prove it but i cant use dart sass because i am using a proyect that previusly use node 12 and node-sass so if i use dart sass it will give a error of version

Comment: didnt work :( i will put the logs of heroku